# Getting exponent value using bit shifts (C, C++)

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

If I have

```c
FLAG_VAL = 1 << 6; //(or 64),
```

how can I get back the exponent (6 in this case) later in the code using FLAG_VAL and bit shifts?

Thank you.

Comment: Count the number of low-order zero bits.

Comment: @Barmar this is valid only if there're no other bit set. The result is not correct if FLAG_VAL was 7. Obviously if FLAG_VAL is obtained always whit shifting 1 your suggestion is correct.

Comment: @SirJoBlack It's not merging the old value of `FLAG_VAL`, it's just assigning it.

Comment: Assuming exactly one bit set to 1: `int count = 0; for (int k = FLAG_VAL; k != 1; k >>= 1) ++count;`